# Create CVS user when a LDAP user is created

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, openldap, ubuntu-8.04, cvs

I am running `ubuntu LDAP server` and also `CVS` is installed on the server. I had to migrate my ldap server to the new ubuntu edition and it's migrated. I will be using `webmin` to administer some things. In the webmin there is an option to select so that whenever a LDAP user is created a CVS user is also created with same name & password of ldap user. In the new ubuntu server the cvs users are not created for the imported(from old) ldap users. If I create the ldap user from the webmin tool, the cvs user is created for that ldap user and it's fine but the problem is cvs users are not created for the imported ldap users.

Does anyone know how to import/create cvs users for the existing ldap users(imported) or is there a way to make it create automatically while importing ldap users?. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Anybody has got any idea?

Comment: If there is any way to export only cvs users then it's better importing them to the new server!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, I could able to see all CVS users from the migrated ldap. 
Where I did wrong is, I installed the cvs service just after migrating the ldap users. And I was checking all the CVS user in the cvs users list on the webmin tool for the migrated ldap users.

The key is, the CVS repositories should also be migrated after migrating the ldap users. Then it lists all the CVS users.